# Grandparent to child method call

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there a way to call child component method from grandparent component? Or the only way to achieve this is to call the parent method first, and from parent calling the child.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each component is a "black box" in the sense that a parent component cannot access a child component's interior components (or, stated differently, a grandparent component cannot access a grandchild component). So, the only way to access a "grandchild" is if the grandparent owns it directly.

For example, this won't work:

```
<template> <!-- grandparent -->
 <c-child></c-child>
</template>
```

...

```
<template> <!-- child -->
  <c-grandchild></c-grandchild>
</template>
```

However, if the grandparent creates the grandchild, then it does work:

```
<template> <!-- grandparent -->
  <c-child>
    <c-grandchild></c-grandchild>
  </c-child>
</template>
```

...

```
<template> <!-- child -->
  <slot></slot> <!-- default slot -->
</template>
```

...

So, your two choices are to either add an [@api method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_javascript_methods) on the child to access the grandchild, or provide a [slot](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_slots) (default or named) so the child no longer directly owns the component.